# Are there any videos that contains verses of Quran being recited by a group or people at a time or an acapella?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation

Is there any videos that contains verses of the Quran being recited by a group of people at a time or an acapella?

I saw the video of it yesterday and i wonder that are there others like it too?

https://youtu.be/U8UPL-5BhAI

Here's the video of it, but i want other videos like it.

Comment: Reciting qur'an in a group is only accepted for studying (learning) purposes any other reason could be at least disliked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salaam,
If you search "Quran in a group" on Youtube, there are multiple videos that you will be able to find. Here is an example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E81ruEZle_4
Hope that helps:)